# How to update specific field /TextView without affecting other views in Android?

Tags: android

I work to make a chat application in android.And now I am making a feature of "last seen".But I didn't find any idea for update specific field /`TextView` without affecting other `view`s.
When the server send to event for last seen, I want to update only lastSeen `TextView` on `Activity` without affecting other `view`s?How can I do that?

I hope I could tell.

Comment: yes, relativeLayout.And only change Textview's value."online","offline" etc.

Comment: when you are chatting a person,and maybe a person is offline.So I want to change only online to offline in Chat page without affecting other views.